# Alterar/ abreviar palavras de um conjunto de dados

Tags: r, string

Há alguma função no R que permita alterar uma ou mais palavras do meu conjunto de dados?

Exemplo, alterar a palavra `São Paulo` por `SP`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simples de criar abreviações é com uso da função `abbreviate` do pacote base. Como as palavras podem ter acentuações, usa-se em conjunto a função `iconv` (também do pacote base) para resolver este problema.

Exemplo reproduzível:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(
  estados = c("São Paulo", "Minas Gerais", "Santa Catarina", "Maranhão"), 
  regiao = c("Sudeste", "Sudeste", "Sul", "Nordeste")
)
```

Supondo que queira abreviar para duas (2) letras. Fica assim:

```
abbreviate(names.arg = iconv(x = df_1$estados), 2)
```

Ou crie uma nova coluna, mantendo o banco de dados:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df_1 %>% 
  mutate(acronimos = str_to_upper(abbreviate(iconv(estados), 2)))

#             estados   regiao acronimos
#    1      São Paulo  Sudeste        SP
#    2   Minas Gerais  Sudeste        MG
#    3 Santa Catarina      Sul        SC
#    4       Maranhão Nordeste        MR
```

O `warning`:

> Warning message:
> In abbreviate(iconv(estados), 2) : abbreviate used with non-ASCII chars

Indica apenas um aviso sobre problema de `Encoding`. Mas nada de relevante para o seu caso. Se quiser entender mais sobre isso, leia [aqui](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Encoding.html).